# Function in add_filter() never runs

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin that have this function:

```
function dokan_get_order_status_translated( $status ) {
    switch ($status) {
        case 'completed':
        case 'wc-completed':
            return __( 'Completed', 'dokan-lite' );
            break;

        default:
            return apply_filters( 'dokan_get_order_status_translated', '', $status );
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to override this function in my functions.php child theme with this:

```
function dokan_add_order_status_translated($status){

      switch ($status) {
        case 'completed':
        case 'wc-completed':
            return __( 'Completed', 'dokan-lite' );
            break;

        case 'failed':
        case 'wc-failed':
            return __( 'Failed', 'dokan-lite' );
            break;
}

add_filter( 'dokan_get_order_status_translated','dokan_add_order_status_translated', 99 );
```

but it the `dokan_add_order_status_translated` never runs.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: How do you know it's not being run? What does your function do?

Comment: I've written a `var_dump('test'); exit;` inside the function `dokan_add_order_status_translated` to test if it's running. This function returns some strings that are rendered inside html tags. I'm going to edit the question with the complete function.

Comment: I can't edit with the complete function because stackoverflow says that there is too much code in my question :/. But the function is a swich() returning strings. In my new function I copied this switch and added some cases.

Comment: Try shrinking the code you use in your function (eg. replace the switch with a single variable, etc), all we want to see is what is it your function does.

Comment: Ok, I shrinked the code removing some cases from the switch and could edit it, thanks for the tip

Comment: Alright, now that you added some more code: the plugin you're using won't run your filter function _unless_ the status is anything but `completed` or `wc-completed`. Are you trying to customize the message string for `failed` and `wc-failed` only?

Comment: Actually the plugin have other `cases` in the `switch` and not just the completed case. I'm trying to add 3 more status cases. I've tried to run the `var_dump(); exit;` function before the `switch-case` structure and nothing happened.

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to use the `dokan_get_order_status_translated` hook which runs only when none of the switch cases have been matched. If that's the case (and apparently [it is](https://github.com/chiotis/centralgreecemarket/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/dokan-lite/includes/order-functions.php#L436-L474)) then you won't be able to substitute the status message as you intend to. Ask the plugin developer to add a new filter hook at the end of the function so you can replace any status message with your own.

Comment: Now i understood what you mean, I've finally got this working. You helped a lot @cabrerahector, thank you! I could add the status because I want to add it only if none of the status before are matched.

Comment: Glad to know you were able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filter `dokan_get_order_status_translated` is providing two arguments: An empty string as a default and the `$status`, so your filter should probably look something like this:

```
add_filter( 'dokan_get_order_status_translated','dokan_add_order_status_translated', 99, 2 );
function dokan_add_order_status_translated( $default, $status ) {
  ...
}
```

Also make sure you're testing with statuses that aren't handled in the original function `dokan_get_order_status_translated`, since the filter won't be called otherwise.